# C++ Official Operator Names / Keywords

Tags: c++, operators, keyword

Happy Holidays guys.

I have been working on a C++ preprocessor sequence (using boost) to assist me in generating operator based functors. I have so far completed the source, however I was having trouble finding the most appropriate keywords identifying these functors.

More specifically after reviewing the C++0x draft I failed to find the most appropriate (unique) names for the following operators:

- -> and . which are both called in the draft: class member operators
- ->* and .* which are both called: pointer to member operators

Do you think you can help me name them better?

The references I have used so for:

1. The C++0x draft (Can be find online)
2. The ["boost/proto/operators.hpp"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf) header which included most of the over-loadable operators.
3. The [Operators in C and C++](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/proto/operators.hpp) from Wikipedia which also provided the following names

   - . structure reference
   - -> structure dereference
   - ->* and .* member pointers

Here is the list I have so far created. Any other suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
 Symbol        Keyword           Description
++      , post_increment      , post increment
--      , post_decrement      , post decrement
++      , pre_increment       , pre increment
--      , pre_decrement       , pre decrement
+       , unary_plus          , additive promotion
-       , unary_minus         , additive inversion
!       , negate              , logical negation
~       , complement          , complement
*       , indirect            , indirection
&       , address_of          , address of
+       , add                 , addition
-       , subtract            , subtraction
*       , multiplies          , multiplication
/       , divides             , division
%       , modulus             , modulo
==      , equal               , equality
!=      , inequal             , inequality
>       , greater             , greater than
<       , less                , less than
>=      , greater_equal       , greater or equal than
<=      , less_equal          , less or equal than
&&      , logical_and         , logical and
||      , logical_or          , logical or
&       , bitwise_and         , bitwise and
|       , bitwise_or          , bitwise inclusive or
^       , bitwise_xor         , bitwise exclusive or
<<      , left_shift          , left shift
>>      , right_shift         , right shift
+=      , add_assign          , addition assignment
-=      , subtract_assign     , subtractions assignment
*=      , multiplies_assign   , multiplication assignment
/=      , divides_assign      , division assignment
%=      , modulus_assign      , modulo assignment
>>=     , right_shift_assign  , right shift assignment
<<=     , left_shift_assign   , left shift assignment
&=      , bitwise_and_assign  , bitwise and assignment
^=      , bitwise_or_assign   , bitwise exclusive or assignment
|=      , bitwise_or_assign   , bitwise inclusive or assignment
->*     , arrow_indirect      , pointer to member
,       , comma               , comma
=       , assign              , assignment
[]      , subscript           , subscription
->      , arrow               , class member
.       , dot                 , class member
.*      , dot_indirect        , pointer to member
```

Comment: I remember this only (not sure) : `->` is called arrow operator (save your eye :D)(member access via pointer)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: I used to be a programmer like you. Then I took an arrow operator in the knee...

Comment: @ChrisParton what does that "Used to be" mean, what you're now? and Why would you do that knee part? 0_o

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Sorry, it was terrible I know haha. I couldn't resist :)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: The game Skyrim contains a lot of soldiers that say a similar thing. It's become quite an annoying trend to paraphrase it online. I was ripping it off.

I'm still a programmer, and my knees are perfectly fine :)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis Thanks, that is what I used after all!

Comment: Don't we still miss ::, I think it was called the resolution scope operator or something like that.

Comment: @Christian Veenman Well yes, but that operator can't be overloaded with C++ hence I never included in the list. The only other operator that can't be overloaded is the (.) which is called member selector.

Comment: Okay no problem! I was just trying to help!

Comment: The standard itself gives names to (only!) some of the operators to define named functors http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional. However it is inconsistent within itself and with your list. Because it calls `multiplies` to `o*o` but `plus` (not `addition` or `add`) to `o+o`. In the first case it describes the operation and in the second case it described the symbol. I think they should be called either `composition` and `plus` OR `multiplies` and `adds` OR `multiplication` and `addition` OR `multiply` and `add`.

Answer (score 11):

Try [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

New, delete, casting, I think there are some more operators and keywords there.